# How to find if there's exists an integer X that fullfil this equation

Tags: modules

Given A, B, C & D and the equation :

> (A*X + B)%D = C

I tried to move the modulo to the other side but I end up with 2 unknown variables.

Comment: What is the % ? Do you mean $\equiv$ ? instead?

Comment: So what do you want to do, specifically? Solve for X? Maybe you can try giving values to A, B, C and D and seeing what happens.

Comment: @dmtri No, It's (AX+B) mod D = C

Comment: @MattiP. Trying to check if there's exists an integer X or not without brute force method

Comment: I think you can assume A%D = A (remains unchanged) and B%D = B. In that case, you can write AX+B = C + kD for some k ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $$AX+B\equiv C\mod D$$
or$$AX\equiv C-B=B'\mod D$$let $$E=\gcd(A,B',D)$$ then the latter equation is equivalent to $${A\over E}X\equiv {B'\over E}\mod {{D\over E}}$$by redefining the variables, we finally obtain$$PX\equiv Q\mod R$$where $$\gcd(P,Q,R)=1$$ note that $\gcd(P,R)=1$ (a proof is easy by definition of $\gcd$) therefore if $X_0$ is a particular solution, i.e. $PX_0\equiv Q\mod R$ then all the solutions are of the form $$X=Ru+X_0\quad,\quad u\in \Bbb Z$$